# Unique hashtag extracting

Tags: java, array

I am trying to find unique hashtags from a tweet that a user inputs.  I have the code to find the number of times a word is used in the input, but I just need to know the number of different hashtags used. For example, in the input

```
#one #two blue red #one #green four
```

there would be 3 unique hashtags as `#one`, `#two`, and `#green`. I cannot figure out how to code this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tweet {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner hashtag = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Please enter a line of text" );
    String userInput = hashtag.nextLine();

    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "\\W", " " );     // strip out any non words.
    userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "  ", " " );      // strip out any double spaces
                                                        //   created from stripping out non words
                                                        //   in the first place!
    String[] tokens = userInput.split( " " );
    System.out.println( userInput );

    ArrayList< String > tweet = new ArrayList< String >();

    tweet.addAll( Arrays.asList( tokens ) );

    int count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < tweet.size(); i++ )
    {
        System.out.printf( "%s: ", tweet.get( i ) );
        for( int j = 0; j < tweet.size(); j++ )
        {
            if( tweet.get( i ).equals( tweet.get( j ) ) )
                count++;
            if( tweet.get( i ).equals( tweet.get( j ) ) && count > 1 )
                tweet.remove( j );                      // after having counted at least
        }                                               // one, remove duplicates from List        
        System.out.printf( "%d\n", count );
        count = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You might consider using a [`Set<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to hold the hashtags.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not program for one purpose and then you will throw it away i will not put to much code in main method. I would just initialize the application, inputs and outputs in main and than call start, run or some other method.

Also represent tweet as an object with methods `Tweet#parse` `Tweet#getHashTags` and so on. Or you can Create TweetParser and separate it even more, but i think in this case it is overkill.

For tokenizing the string use built-in class [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)
And use Set as suggested in comment.

My Tweet class:

```
package scjp.tweet;

import java.util.*;

public class Tweet {

    private final List<String> hashtags = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String text;

    private Tweet() {}

    public static Tweet getTweet(String tweetText) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.text = tweetText;
        tweet.parse();
        return tweet;
    }

    private void parse() {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(this.text);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if (token.startsWith("#")) {
                hashtags.add(token);
            }
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getUniqueHashtags() {
        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
        unique.addAll(hashtags);
        return unique;
    }

}
```

And main class:

```
package scjp.tweet;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TweetMain {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner hashtag = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Please enter a line of text" );
        String tweetText = hashtag.nextLine();

        Tweet tweet = Tweet.getTweet(tweetText.toLowerCase());

        System.out.println(tweet.getUniqueHashtags());
    }
}
```